# Yql import error in python

Tags: python, yql

I am trying to import Yql but it throws the following error.I am using using ubuntu 10.04.

```
>>>import yql

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yql/__init__.py", line 563, in <module>
    class YahooToken(oauth.Token):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Token'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

There were other libraries that were messing with Yql.I removed python-oauth2,oauth2,Yql and reinstalled Yql.

```
sudo pip uninstall python-oauth2
sudo pip uninstall oauth2
sudo pip  uninstall yql
sudo pip install yql
```